How to solve Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC' in tryuing to install Apache Hbase
When i try to run ./start-hbase.cmd i get the following error:
PS C:\hbasesetup\hbase-2.6.1\bin> ./start-hbase.cmd
Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
ERROR: Could not determine the startup mode.
Please help me !!!
HERE BELOW THERE'S THE PROPERTY THAT I HAVE SETTED FOLLOWING THIS VIDEO https://youtube.com/watch?v=oTAhcXRIDfA&t=183s
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
-->
<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>C:\Hfile</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
  <value>C:\zookeeper</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9820/hbase</value>
</property>

NOTICE THAT: I HAVE REMOVED THIS PIECE FROM THE ORIGINAL FILE ABOVE (can be it the problem ?)
<!--
    The following properties are set for running HBase as a single process on a
    developer workstation. With this configuration, HBase is running in
    "stand-alone" mode and without a distributed file system. In this mode, and
    without further configuration, HBase and ZooKeeper data are stored on the
    local filesystem, in a path under the value configured for `hbase.tmp.dir`.
    This value is overridden from its default value of `/tmp` because many
    systems clean `/tmp` on a regular basis. Instead, it points to a path within
    this HBase installation directory.

    Running against the `LocalFileSystem`, as opposed to a distributed
    filesystem, runs the risk of data integrity issues and data loss. Normally
    HBase will refuse to run in such an environment. Setting
    `hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce` to `false` overrides this behavior,
    permitting operation. This configuration is for the developer workstation
    only and __should not be used in production!__

    See also https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#standalone_dist
  -->
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>./tmp</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
</configuration>

